# how to filter nested objects properties in javascript and print the new object

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I got object that built like this,it is dynamicly so i dont't know how many nested objects will be and the outside object keys .The only known keys outside is "bids",and inside is (needed properties).

```
let data= {
  "/9968336/header-bid-tag-0": {
    "bids": [
      {
        "bidderCode": "appnexus",
        "width": 300,
        "height": 250,
        "statusMessage": "Bid available",
        "adId": "7a53a9d3",
        "creative_id": 29681110,
        "cpm": 0.5,
        "adUrl": "https://nym1.ib.adnxs.com/ab?e=wqT_3QLzBKBqAgAAAgDWAAUIkav6sAUQucfc0v-nzQcYj…r=http%3A%2F%2Flocal%3A4000%2Fexamples%2Fpbjs_partial_refresh_example.html",
        "requestTimestamp": 1444844944095,
        "responseTimestamp": 1444844944180,
        "timeToRespond": 85,
        "adUnitCode": "/19968336/header-bid-tag-0",
        "bidder": "appnexus",
        "usesGenericKeys": true,
        "size": "300x250",
        "adserverTargeting": {
          "hb_bidder": "appnexus",
          "hb_adid": "7a53a9d3",
          "hb_pb": "0.50"
        }
      },{
        "bidderCode": "pubmatic",
        "width": "300",
        "height": "250",
        "statusMessage": "Bid available",
        "adId": "1139e34e14",
        "adSlot": "39620189@300x250",
        "cpm": 1,
        "ad": "<span class=\"PubAPIAd\"><script src='https://ad.turn.com/server/ads.js?pub=5757398&cch=36757096&code=37127675&l=3…tcGlkPUVERkNGMDY5LTA2ODctNDAxQy04NkMwLTIzQjNFNzI1MzdGNiZwYXNzYmFjaz0w_url='></script></span> <!-- PubMatic Ad Ends -->",
        "adUrl": "https://aktrack.pubmatic.com/AdServer/AdDisplayTrackerServlet?operId=1&pubId…local%3A4000%2Fexamples%2Fpbjs_partial_refresh_example.html&lpu=hotels.com",
        "dealId": "",
        "requestTimestamp": 1444844944105,
        "responseTimestamp": 1444844944354,
        "timeToRespond": 249,
        "adUnitCode": "/19968336/header-bid-tag-0",
        "bidder": "pubmatic",
        "usesGenericKeys": true,
        "size": "300x250",
        "adserverTargeting": {
          "hb_bidder": "pubmatic",
          "hb_adid": "1139e34e14",
          "hb_pb": "1.00"
        }
      },
      {
        "bidderCode": "rubicon",
        "width": "300",
        "height": "250",
        "statusMessage": "Bid available",
        "adId": "130d3b0d9b",
        "cpm": 0.795995,
        "ad": "<scri...pt>",
        "ad_id": "3161645",
        "sizeId": "15",
        "requestTimestamp": 1444844944116,
        "responseTimestamp": 1444844944396,
        "timeToRespond": 280,
        "adUnitCode": "/19968336/header-bid-tag-0",
        "bidder": "rubicon",
        "usesGenericKeys": true,
        "size": "300x250",
        "adserverTargeting": {
          "hb_bidder": "rubicon",
          "hb_adid": "130d3b0d9b",
          "hb_pb": "0.50"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "/9968336/header-bid-tag1": {
    "bids": [
      {
        "bidderCode": "casale",
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "statusMessage": "Bid returned empty or error response",
        "adId": "108c0ba49d",
        "requestTimestamp": 1444844944130,
        "responseTimestamp": 1444844944223,
        "timeToRespond": 93,
        "cpm": 6,
        "adUnitCode": "/19968336/header-bid-tag1",
        "bidder": "casale"
      },
      {
        "bidderCode": "openx",
        "width": "728",
        "height": "90",
        "statusMessage": "Bid available",
        "adId": "14d7f9208f",
        "ad_id": "537161420",
        "cpm": 1.717,
        "ad": "<iframe src=...tame>",
        "requestTimestamp": 1444844944130,
        "responseTimestamp": 1444844944490,
        "timeToRespond": 360,
        "adUnitCode": "/19968336/header-bid-tag1",
        "bidder": "openx",
        "usesGenericKeys": true,
        "size": "728x90",
        "adserverTargeting": {
          "hb_bidder": "openx",
          "hb_adid": "14d7f9208f",
          "hb_pb": "1.50"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and I want to clear from the inside object all the keys and value except (cpm,bidder,adUnitCode)
and return the new object with only this properties

I am strurgle here
that what I tray to do
so far

```
 for(let propName in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        let propValue = data[propName];
        for(var insideProp in propValue.bids) {
          if(propValue.bids.hasOwnProperty(insideProp)) {
              let insideValue=propValue.bids[insideProp]
              for(let insideLvl2 in insideValue) {
                   if(insideLvl2!=='cpm'){
                     insideValue.insideLvl2=null;
                     console.log(insideValue.insideLvl2);
                   }
              }
               
             }
          
        
        }
    }
}
```

thanx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want `cpm, bidder, adUnitCode` in the resultant object then you can easily do using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
  acc[k] = {
    ...v,
    bids: v.bids.map(({ cpm, bidder, adUnitCode }) => ({
      cpm,
      bidder,
      adUnitCode,
    })),
  };
  return acc;
}, {});
```

**EDITED:** If you want to return `cpm=null` if the is no `cpm` property in the object itself then you can do as:

```
Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
  acc[k] = {
    ...v,
    bids: v.bids.map(({ cpm = null, bidder = null, adUnitCode = null }) => ({   // change
      cpm,
      bidder,
      adUnitCode,
    })),
  };
  return acc;
}, {})
```

```js
let data = {
  "/9968336/header-bid-tag1": {
    bids: [
      {
        bidderCode: "casale",
        statusMessage: "Bid returned empty or error response",
        adId: "108c0ba49d",
        requestTimestamp: 1444844944130,
        responseTimestamp: 1444844944223,
        timeToRespond: 93,
        adUnitCode: "/19968336/header-bid-tag1",
        bidder: "casale",
      },
    ],
  },
};

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
  acc[k] = {
    ...v,
    bids: v.bids.map(({ cpm = null, bidder = null, adUnitCode = null }) => ({
      cpm,
      bidder,
      adUnitCode,
    })),
  };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanx for this it is good but , how I makes sure that values in the inside object present and make if statment for example :if(cpm not found do x )

Comment: tell me the whole scenario with an example and what should be your expected output?

Comment: the inside object(last lvl is dynamic,so in some cases some of the parameters can not exisst for example :` let data= {
 "/9968336/header-bid-tag1": {
    "bids": [
      {
        "bidderCode": "casale",
        "statusMessage": "Bid returned empty or error response",
        "adId": "108c0ba49d",
        "requestTimestamp": 1444844944130,
        "responseTimestamp": 1444844944223,
        "timeToRespond": 93,
        "adUnitCode": "/19968336/header-bid-tag1",
        "bidder": "casale"
      }`     in this case I want return same object but cpm=null @decpk

Comment: @Romka edited code, have a look

Comment: thanx it working well :>